opening a cash drawer connected directly to PC for a Windows Form application without a printer
I'm currently working on a Windows Form application where I need to control a cash drawer directly connected to the PC via an RJ11 port. Importantly, I am not using a printer as an intermediary - the cash drawer is connected directly.
I've been trying to use C# to send the necessary commands to open the drawer, but I seem to be hitting a roadblock.
Here's what I've tried so far:
// Create a new SerialPort instance
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(selectedPort);

// Configure the serial port
Encoding enc = Encoding.Unicode;
serialPort.Encoding = enc;
serialPort.BaudRate = 38400;
serialPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
serialPort.DtrEnable = true;

// Open the serial port
serialPort.Open();

// Write data to the serial port
serialPort.Write(char.ConvertFromUtf32(28699) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(9472) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(3365));

Unfortunately, this method doesn't seem to be working for me. The cash drawer doesn't open when I execute the code. I've tried sending different commands as well, but nothing seems to be working.
If anyone has experience with controlling a cash drawer directly from a Windows application via an RJ11 port without using a printer as an intermediary, I would greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions. Are there any specific commands I should be sending, or perhaps there's an issue with my code that I'm overlooking?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The UTF-32 character 28699 is "瀛", which seems like an unlikely character to send to a cash drawer. What does the specification for the cash drawer actually say to send it? Can you provide a link to the specification?

Have you verified that the cable and device work outside of your application - is there any test or utility software that comes with the cash drawer you could use to verify?

@canton7 Your point about using the byte[] overload was valid though, in the absence of documentation about the cash drawer protocol, that would have been my guess as to how to fix this.
